# Access-Control-Allow-Origin in .htaccess didnt work in sub directories

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, xmlhttprequest, webserver

I have an error when I try to convert image from URL to base 64, the error is

> Access to image at >'https://img.blabla.com/user/profile_pict/1541043536539.jpg' from >origin >'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No >'Access->Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I've tried so much to fix this error, some peope said " You should put `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` in .htaccess on `https://img.blabla.com/` ", so I tried put .htaccess, like this.

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
    RewriteRule ^(/(.*))?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>`

`<FilesMatch "\.(gif|png|css|js|jpg)$">
    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "*"
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
    </ifModule>
</FilesMatch>`

.htaccess just works in `/index.html`. it didnt works in sub directories. Let say I have a website with this structure:

`/index.html
/.htaccess
/user/profile_pict/*.jpg
/travel_agent/trip/*.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the .htaccess of the external root folder :

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

And if it only concerns .jpg images you should wrap the above code inside this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg)$">
...
</FilesMatch>
```

There is other more methods to use **.htaccess**, you can go to the directory and create .htaccess file there that .htaccess file will specific only for that directory.
alternatively
You can also define directory path from your root **.htaccess**

Comment: are you using node or apache? and what programming language?

Comment: I'm using apache, xml for setting .htaccess

Comment: what do you mean by you are using xml for .htaccess? 
htaccess file name used to be .htaccess and nothing else.   ok, it may be a case your .htaccess is not working just open .htaccess file and type dnasndfawndfwo random characters and your website will stop working. if it still work after editing .htaccess file with random character that means you need to configure apache so that your .htaccess will work